# How to mix two colours randomly in a texture?

Tags: modeling

I m modeling this glasses and i want the texture exactly like this. Blue and Black mix glossy type finish.
I have tried mixing two colors using MixRGB nodes but i don't[image] mix randomly it mixes evenly.
So how can i get a finish like this? Blue and Black mixtures of colors?

Comment: Are you talking about the front part, or the lighter blue visible on left?

Comment: I don't think it's random. This is a dark transparent material and that's why the thicker parts are black.